# Xcode 9: Documentation and Toolchains not showing in Preferences > Components

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

As shown in screenshot below, how is this an intended change by apple?

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://swift.org/download/#snapshots and download the snapshots of your choosing (these are the toolchains). Once installed, a new submenu option will appear as `Xcode -> Toolchains -> Manage Toolchains...`.

Hitting `Manage Toolchains...` will open `Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> Toolchains`. You'll be able to select Swift's Toolchain from there.

Cheers!